# Calculate $\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{y}$ indirectly without accessing $\mathbf{A}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-equations, pseudoinverse

**The Original Question (informal):**

I have a black-box linear system $f:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^M~(0\ll M\ll N)$. It is guaranteed that there exists a full-rank matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ satisfying $\forall \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N,f(\mathbf{x})\equiv\mathbf{Ax}$. Here I call $\mathbf{A}$ the transformation matrix of $f$.

Now given a vector $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^M$, I want to calculate $\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^N$, where $\mathbf{A}^+\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times M}$, satisfying $\mathbf{AA}^+=\mathbf{I}_M$ in some cases, is the Moore–Penrose inverse of $\mathbf{A}$ ([Reference 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)).

There are some supplementary information:

1. I may know that there is a way to get the explicit form of $\mathbf{A}$ from a given fixed $f$ ([Reference 2](https://www.mathbootcamps.com/matrix-linear-transformation/)). However, since $M$ and $N$ are both very large numbers (about $10^6$ or even $10^9$), I would not get $\mathbf{A}$, explicitly calculate $\mathbf{A}^+$, and finally calculate $\mathbf{z=A}^+\mathbf{y}$. (The computational complexity of direct calculation is too high for me.) I may want an indirect way of obtaining $\mathbf{z=A}^+\mathbf{y}$.
2. The inner structure of linear $f$ is very complicated. Actually, $f$ is a black-box. But in my system, I can conveniently calculate $f(\mathbf{r})$ for any given $\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^N$. In other words, the forward pass of $f$ is fast and efficient.
3. I may not need $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{A}^+$ or some operators about them. I may only want $\mathbf{z=A}^+\mathbf{y}$, which is known to be unique when $\mathbf{y}$ and $f$ are given and fixed.
4. There are no prior knowledge about $f$, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. In other words, their inner values or elements can be random numbers, like some noise.

So, how to get $\mathbf{z=A}^+\mathbf{y}$ efficiently?

---

**Some of My Efforts:**

I was trying to search an $\mathbf{x}$ satisfying $\mathbf{Ax=y}$. To be concrete, I use a tool dubbed PyTorch (a deep learning framework on Python) to optimize a randomly initialized $\mathbf{x}$ with a loss function $\mathcal{L}=\lVert f(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y} \rVert _2^2$. And $f$ is a neural network in my own implementation. When $\mathcal{L}$ hits $0$, I stop my optimization program and get the estimation.

However, since $0\ll M\ll N$, there may exist $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ satisfying $\mathbf{x}_1\ne \mathbf{x}_2$ and $\mathbf{Ax}_1=\mathbf{Ax}_2=\mathbf{y}$. Therefore, I think this method could not exactly find the unique $\mathbf{z=A}^+\mathbf{y}$ that I want.

Does there exists an efficient way to achieve this?

There may be two statements (but in fact, only one of them is true):

1. The answer is "Yes". There exists a way to efficiently calculate $\mathbf{z=A}^+\mathbf{y}$ from given fixed $f$ and $\mathbf{y}$, without accessing the explicit forms of $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{A}^+$. In other words, there are some properties of $\mathbf{z=A}^+\mathbf{y}$ can be utilized. But I have still not found them.
2. The answer is "No". To get $\mathbf{z=A}^+\mathbf{y}$, I should try to get the explicit form of $\mathbf{A}^+$ and then calculate $\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{y}$. There are no efficient and indirect ways.

After a long struggle, I still have no idea about this problem. Now I may tend to believe that the above second statement is true.

Any solutions, suggestions and discussions about this problem would be appealing for me.

I am still searching, trying and thinking ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [Moore-Penrose inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) includes the following formula, valid if $\mathbf A$ has linearly independent rows: $$\mathbf A^+ = \mathbf A^T (\mathbf A \mathbf A^T)^{-1}$$ where I've replaced their $\mathbf A^*$ with $\mathbf A^T$ because your matrix entries are real-valued.

You said we can assume $\mathbf A$ has full rank, so this formula is valid in your case. (There's also a separate formula that instead assumes $\mathbf A$ has l.i. *columns*, which would obviously be false since you have $M \ll N$.)

You can use this formula to compute $\mathbf z = \mathbf A^+ \mathbf y$ without building $A^+$. In particular:

1. Find a solution $\mathbf{v}$ to the system $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{y}$.
2. The final vector you want is $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{v}$.

Step (2) is easy if your black box allows you some way to efficiently compute $\mathbf A^T \mathbf v$ for an input vector $\mathbf v \in \mathbf{R}^M$.

Step (1) looks hard, but actually this is a well-studied problem; see the Wikipedia article on "[matrix-free methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix-free_methods)" which exactly refers to finding approximate solutions to linear systems when we only access the matrix as a black box. These methods mostly come down to multiplying by the linear system's matrix a bunch of times. In your case, to multiply by $\mathbf A \mathbf A^T$ you should *not* build the full matrix; instead you could take a starting vector $\mathbf u_0$, then compute $\mathbf u_1 = \mathbf A^T \mathbf u_0$, then finally compute $u_2 = \mathbf A \mathbf u_1$. The step $\mathbf u_1 \mapsto \mathbf u_2$ is just an application of your black box function $f$. The step $\mathbf u_0 \mapsto \mathbf u_1$ again relies on you having some relatively efficient method for applying $\mathbf v \mapsto \mathbf A^T \mathbf v$.

---

In summary, you should look at the details of how you're computing $f$ and see if you can set up a similar black-box way to efficiently compute $\mathbf 
A^T \mathbf v$ for input vectors $\mathbf v \in \mathbb{R}^M$. If you can do that, then the above strategy will let you multiply by $\mathbf A^+$ way more efficiently than fully building+storing $\mathbf A^+$.

Comment: I particularly thank @DavidClyde for his/her effort and kindly providing such a long and detailed answer. I can understand it. I would like to accept this answer and try this solution. I believe that it will work for me.

Comment: @BinChen Glad to hear it! Good luck with the implementation - especially with finding a matrix-free linear solver algorithm that works reasonably fast + accurate for your particular problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to David's answer, there is neither a reason nor a necessity to assume $A^⊤v$ is easily computable in this case. Nevertheless, matrix free methods are the right tool. Consider the following characterization of the pseudoinverse:

$$ A^+y = \operatorname*{arg\,min}_{x∈S(A, y)} ‖x‖^2 \qquad S(A,y) = \operatorname*{arg\,min}_{x} ‖Ax-y‖^2$$

That is, the Pseudoinverse is the **minimal norm solution** among all minimizers of $‖Ax-y‖^2$ (notice that $S(A,y)$ is an infinite set if the system is underdetermined). Equivalently, we can write

$$ x^*(λ) = \operatorname*{arg\,min}_{x}‖Ax-y‖^2 + λ‖x‖^2 $$

Which has a **unique** solution for all $λ>0$ due to strict convexity. One can show that $A^+y = \lim_{λ→0} x^*(λ)$, i.e. the pseudoinverse essentially gives the value for an infinitesimal amount of $L^2$-regularization. This gives immediately the following algorithm:

```
Initialize λ, x randomly.

while not converged:
   x = minimize(‖Az-y‖² + λ‖z‖², z₀=x)
   λ = shrink(λ)  # for example λ/2

return x
```

This is called a **homotopy method**, because we gradually transform the regularized problem into the unregularized problem while carrying the solution along with us.

Comment: This answer is significant for me and brings me great gains. I learn from it that $\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{y}$ is the solution of equation $\mathbf{Ax=y}$ with minimal norm. The result is unique. I may know $\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{y}$ and the $L^2$-regularization before (the latter is widely studied/used in optimization and machine/deep learning), and establish a connection between them in my mind, just now.

Comment: I have to say that the method provided by @Hyperplane may be actually more practical for me. Since the linear system $f$ is a neural network (with no activations) in my case, the optimization can be conveniently implemented in deep learning frameworks like PyTorch.

Comment: In addition, I want to supplement that $\mathbf{A}^\top\mathbf{v}$ could be obtained in my case, for any given $\mathbf{v}$. To be concrete, I use a tool named `autograd` of PyTorch and (automatically) compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\lVert f(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{v} \rVert_2^2\right]=-\mathbf{A}^\top(\mathbf{Ax-v})$ at the point of $\mathbf{x=0}_N$. However, it is not guaranteed to be always computable for all situations.

Comment: Before reading this answer, inspired by @DavidClyde, my original solution was finding a $\mathbf{v}$ satisfying $\mathbf{AA^\top v=y}$ for given $\mathbf{y}$, through minimizing $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\lVert \mathbf{AA^\top v-y}\rVert _2^2$. For initialization $\mathbf{v}_0$, I may manually implement gradient descent $\mathbf{v}_{k+1}=\mathbf{v}_{k}-\eta\mathbf{AA^\top}(\mathbf{AA^\top v}_{k}-\mathbf{y})$ to find $\mathbf{v}^*$, and finally compute $\mathbf{z=A^\top v}^*=\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{y}$. Note that $\mathbf{A}(\cdot)$ and $\mathbf{A}^\top(\cdot)$ are both computable in my case.

Comment: I am feeling a bit silly now because I find that the website of Wikipedia [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse ] I referenced has already given the property of minimum norm.

Comment: I would particularly thank @Hyperplane for providing this answer. I will perform some experiments as soon as possible.

Comment: @BinChen You might want to look into how [`scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html) and [`scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr) solve the problem. [`torch.linalg.lstsq`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.lstsq.html#torch-linalg-lstsq) unfortunately does not provide a way to specify the initial guess and is based on a SVD afaik which may run into memory and stability issues.